# Standalone program can see license

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-license-manager

I used standart license initialization code in C# standalone program. It was working perfectly on 10.1 and 10.2. But after migrating to 10.3 it says Licenses are not available. Meanwhile ArcMap and ArcCatalog opens with no prob. Any idea why it may be happening?

```
            m_AOLicenseInitializer = new LicenseInitializer();
            if (!m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication
                (new esriLicenseProductCode[] 
                {   esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced, 
                    esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic, 
                    esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeStandard, 
                    esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeEngine,
                    esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeEngineGeoDB,
                    esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcServer
                },new esriLicenseExtensionCode[]{}))  
            {
                MessageBox.Show(m_AOLicenseInitializer.LicenseMessage());
                returnValue = false;   
                m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();
            }
```

it says that none of the licenses exits.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the minimum license requirements for your application? ArcMap (ArcCatalog) can be run with a basic license level. Your application may need an advanced license level? Furthermore you should share some code in your question to get better answers.

Comment: ArcMap and Catalog from "About" menu, says license level is Advanced. But you are right about question. Will correct now.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all other license checks and only retain Advanced level license:

```cs
            m_AOLicenseInitializer = new LicenseInitializer();
            if (!m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication
                (new esriLicenseProductCode[] 
                {   esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced
                }, new esriLicenseExtensionCode[] { }))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(m_AOLicenseInitializer.LicenseMessage());
                returnValue = false;
                m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();
            }
```

As a better replacement for ArcEngine application, I highliy recommend to use License Controls (axLicenseControl)

Comment: same. Advanced not found. Will try axLicenseControl and write back.

Comment: not a solution. sorry.